# Place a normal ProgressBar to the exact location of a ToolStripProgressBar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, progress-bar

In C# or VBNET How I can place at runtime a normal ProgressBar control (or a 3rd party ProgressBar) to the exact location of the ToolStripProgressBar inside the statusstrip?

I've tried this, but the normal progressbar moves to the upper-left corner and my statusstrip is at the bottom...:

```
ProgressBar1.Size = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Size
ProgressBar1.Location = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Location
```

And with this else happens the same thing:

```
ProgressBar1.Size = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Bounds.Size
ProgressBar1.Location = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Bounds.Location
```

With this the normal progressbar moves to the bottom corner where the statusstrip is but the size/location is not exact, I can see the ToolStripProgressBar1 back of the normal progressbar:

```
ProgressBar1.Size = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Bounds.Size
ProgressBar1.Location = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Parent.Bounds.Location
```

Comment: Why must it be at runtime?  Leave a big space in the status bar (use a fixed size label), draw a meter over that space, set the anchor to left, bottom.  It wont be a 'member' of the status bar or the internal layoutpanel thing, but should remain in place thru moving and resizing.  It would have to be to the LEFT of any dynamic status bar things though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to place a control to cover the existing `ToolStripProgressBar`, but it's fortunately that achieving such a thing is simple. You can just access to the hosted `ProgressBar` via the `ProgressBar` property, use the `PointToScreen` method correctly to get the screen coordinates location of the `ProgressBar`, then convert that location into the form coordinates version and use that for your another ProgressBar. Note that the ProgressBar you used outside should have `Parent` set to your form:

```
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  //handle the Shown event of your form to ensure
  //your toolStripProgressBar1 has been rendered correctly with correct location
  Shown += (s,e) => {
    //suppose you have a progressbar called progressBar1
    progressBar1.Location = PointToClient(toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar
                                               .PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
    //do this to cover the whole existing toolStripProgressBar1 exactly
    progressBar1.Size = toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Size;
    //call this to ensure your progressBar1 lies on top of all other controls of 
    //your form (of course your statusStrip should be a control of your form)
    progressBar1.BringToFront();
  }; 
  //We should also handle the SizeChanged event of the form
  //because when resizing, the location of the toolStripProgressBar (relatively
  // to the form) will change
  SizeChanged += (s, e) => {
    progressBar1.Location = PointToClient(toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar
                                                .PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
  };
}
```